# Camera Request Permission is bringing error

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and i am trying to build a flashlight app. I tried to request permission to use the camera but it is bringing cannot resolve CAMERA_REQUEST. Any explanation and solution. Find the code below.

```
mButtonEnabled = findViewById(R.id.buttonEnable);
    mButtonEnabled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the error you are getting is a compiler error as there is no declaration of CAMERA_REQUEST. This is just a number that you define as an id for the request you are making. Ideally, you should be defining this as an instance variable.

This id will be passed back to you via the method call as the requestCode to help you identify which request the response is for. It will also give the permissions granted respectively as you can request more than one at once:

```
private final int REQUEST_CAMERA_ID = 123456;

public void setupUI() {

    mButtonEnabled = findViewById(R.id.buttonEnable);
    mButtonEnabled.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_ID);
        }
    });
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA_ID:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted
            } else {
                    // Permission was denied
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks richard, It works. It seemed i didnt declare CAMERA_request

Answer (score 0):

You could use any number as CAMERA_REQUEST. Android hasn't this property, it's just your identifier for next working with responses.

Answer (score 0):

Following, I have written code for granting a runtime permissions for Camera, There is a String of Array in which you can give multiple requests granting as which is needed at runtime.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (checkPermission()) {
    //main logic or main code

   // . write your main code to execute, It will execute if the permission is already given.

    } else {
        requestPermission();
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // main logic
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access permissions",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            requestPermission();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}
```

}

Hope It'll help for you

Answer (score 0):

App / manifest /
AndroidManifest.xml

Write the following code inside the file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

add the following code in mainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
```

Hope It'll help for you